# Error with ifthenelse

Tags: conditionals, tcolorbox, ifthenelse

The code

```
\newcommand{\variableBackgroundColor}{%
\ifthenelse{1=1}%\(\boolean{Colle} \OR \boolean{DM}\)}
%then
    {black!10!white}
%else   
    {white}
}


\tcolorboxenvironment{private_exo}{boxrule=0pt,
                                   colframe=white,
                                   colback=\variableBackgroundColor,
                                   breakable,
                                   top=0pt,
                                   bottom=0pt,
                                   left=0pt,
                                   right=0pt,
                                   left skip=0pt,
                                   right skip=0pt,
                                   boxsep=0pt,
                                   sharp corners,
                                   noparskip,
                                   nobeforeafter,
                                   %parbox=false,
                                   }
```

raises the error

> ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 107.  
>                   \fi

Is there something obvious (I'm learning) I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colback` wants a color specification, which `\ifthenelse{1=1}{black!10!white}{white}` isn't. It *appears* to be, but the `\ifthenelse` construct doesn't work by “pure expansion”.

Use a different boolean expression manager, such as `etoolbox`: after `\usepackage{etoolbox}` constructs such as

```
colback=\ifnumcomp{1}{=}{1}{black!10!white}{white}
```

as well as

```
colback=\variableBackgroundColor
```

with `\newcommand{\variableBackgroundColor}{\ifnumcomp{1}{=}{1}{black!10!white}{white}}`
will work.

The admissible relations are `<`, `=` or `>`. See the `etoolbox` manual for more information.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\variableBackgroundColor}{%
  \ifnumcomp{1}{=}{1}{black!10!white}{white}%
}

\newenvironment{private_exo}{}{}

\tcolorboxenvironment{private_exo}{
  boxrule=0pt,
  colframe=white,
  colback=\variableBackgroundColor,
  breakable,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  left skip=0pt,
  right skip=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  sharp corners,
  noparskip,
  nobeforeafter,
  %parbox=false,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{private_exo}
abc
\end{private_exo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @egreg, you're very helpful. I hope `etoolbox` manages also `\or`, etc. What is the ultimate tool for tests in `LaTeX`?

Comment: @Colas `etoolbox` allows boolean expressions; personally, I'd use `expl3`, but it requires a bit of study.